# Branching Logic In SharePoint 2010

Tags: survey

I am new to surveys and SharePoint.

I want to create a SharePoint survey using branching logic. The first question in the survey would ask the respondent to select his/her name from the list of available respondents names (choice with buttons). Based on the name selected, I want my survey to present a certain set of questions to the respondent. Therefore, depending on who the respondent is, they get a different set of questions. I seem to be unable to do this.... Can anyone help? Please and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Surveys are tricky to set up. What you need to do is add in all your questions first, before you define your branching. You need to organize them. For example, if you have some questions based on your first question, and some common, put the common ones at the end so you can easily jump. If you diagram it out like a flowchart you can figure out how to attach them all together.

```
Q1: Who.... choices Person A/B/C
      value A: branch to Q2
      value B: branch to Q4
      value C: branch to Q6
Q2: Person A question 
      no branching, fall through to next
Q3: Person A question
      always branch to Q8 to skip the other people questions
Q4: Person B question
      no branching, fall through to next
Q5: Person B question
      always branch to Q8 to skip the other people questions
Q6: Person C question
      no branching, fall through to next
Q7: Person C question
      always branch to Q8 to skip the other people questions
Q8: Common question 1
Q9: Common question 2
```

Then you go into the survey list settings, and on Q1, you'll see at the bottom it will list all the options and where you want to branch to. So if choice is Person A, you want to branch to Q2. If Person B, you wnat to branch to Q4.

The last question of a person, you want to branch to the last question X, to skip around the others. So on Q3, you want to always branch to Qx.

You may find your branching logic complex enough that you might have to duplicate questions, but that will split apart your graphics and percent answered totals and makes it more difficult.

Comment: Thank you. So Q1 is where I ask for the respondent`s name.  I went into the survey settings and selected Q1. At the bottom, in the Branching Logic section, I see all of the name choices I have entered when I created the question. I am able to select where to jump to for each individual. However this only allows me to jump to one question. I need to be able to attribute more than one question to each respondent. Some questions are common to all respondents, some questions only apply to one. Help?

Comment: If you have all the questions for a name together, the default of 'not branching' will drop through the next questions, then on the last question for the name is when you could branch to a common question section at the end. Sometimes you have to duplicate and reorganize questions. I'll update my example above.